# sqlite jdbc Eclipse database relative path

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to use Sqlite, jdbc under Eclipse Luna & Windows 7.

Everything works fine when I use absolute path to the Sqlite database but when relative path used I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database.

I spent some time Googling this problem and the answer is: Yes you can use relative path with jdbc connection. However it does not work for me.

**My code:**

```
package PortiaMoxy;
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;
String inPath; // incoming file
String outPath; // converted file from incoming file
public File() {
    // Connect to Sqlite db
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        // 
        // This connection works fine
        // 
        //c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/JavaProjects/workspace/Polymorphism/sources/PortiaMoxy/moxyimport.sqlite");


        //
        // This connection doesn't work. ???
        //
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:moxyimport.sqlite");

        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        print("File(): Opened database successfully.");
        stmt = c.createStatement();


        String query = "select ID \"id\", VALUE \"value\"";
        query += "from infiles;";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if (!rs.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
             System.out.println("No data"); 
            } 


        while(rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString(1);
            String value = rs.getString(2);
            print("   ID = " + id + " Value = " + value);
        } // end of while
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();



    } // end of try
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        print(ex.getClass().getName() + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (Exception e ) {
        print(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }



} // end of class

public int convert() {
    print(what());

    print("Generic convert");
    return 0;

}

public String what() {
    return "File";
}

}
```

Comment: same problem this question..research efforts..

Comment: find this solution i got help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your database within the following folder and try again with relative path:

**/JavaProjects/workspace/Polymorphism**

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

> Set the **Relative path** in sqlite jdbc Database connectivity using Eclipse

1) Go to **Run** menu and select **Run Configurations**

2) Select the second tab **(x)=Arguments**

3) in Last Panel or section name is **Working directory**

4) click **other** Radio button

5) click the **File System** or **Workspace** Button and set your project Name

6) click the **apply** button

```
//Import the database in your project workspace like 'Demo.db'
Connection conn = null;

public static void connect()
{
    File dbfile=new File(".");
    String url="jdbc:sqlite:"+dbfile.getAbsolutePath()+"\\Demo.db";
    System.out.println(url);
    try {
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        }

    System.out.println("Connection successfully");
}//end connection()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that without the full path, jdbc will try to locate the database in the *current path*.

I am not completely sure, but I think this should be the root of the project.

So you can put the SQLite file in this directory or use the path